# How to solve java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

I am getting the `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the `cars.add(car);` line and I am really unsure how to solve it, I have read some of the other threads relating to this error, but the answer still seems to have eluded me.

```java
public class RentalCompany {

    private ArrayList<Car> cars;
    private String description;
    private int carDownPayment;
    private int rate;
    private int carNumber;

    public void addCar(String descriptionOfTheCar, int downPayment,
        int dailyRate) {
        Car car = new Car(descriptionOfTheCar, downPayment, dailyRate);
        cars.add(car);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Because you haven't initialized the `private ArrayList<Car> cars` field. Do it either lazily, in a constructor or in the method itself.

```
private ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

OR

```
public RentalCompany() {
    this.cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
}
```

OR

```
public void addCar(String descriptionOfTheCar, int downPayment,
    int dailyRate) {
    this.cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    Car car = new Car(descriptionOfTheCar, downPayment, dailyRate);
    cars.add(car);
}
```

I personally prefer the constructor approach.

Comment: Oh, and I know that a sentence can't begin with 'Because'

Comment: Hmmm... Option 3 overrides `this.cars` with a new ArrayList every time the `addCar` function is called. The content of `this.cars` will be deleted at each `addCar` invocation and `cars` will never contain more than one element.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use:

```
    public void addCar(String descriptionOfTheCar, int downPayment, int dailyRate)
        {
            if (cars == null)
                cars = new ArrayList<>();

            Car car = new Car(descriptionOfTheCar, downPayment, dailyRate);
            cars.add(car);
        }
```

assuming its one thread access

Answer (score 3):

You didn't initiate cars.

```
private ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Init list:

```
private ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

Answer (score 0):

`cars` has not been initialised.

Try adding the following to your constructor:

```
cars = new ArrayList<>();
```

before you add cars to it.

Answer (score 0):

Initially `cars == null`, so initialize it as follow:

```cs
 private ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

Answer (score 0):

your cars was not initialized, which is null. and you tried to add Elements to this null arraylist.

you could initialize it before using.

Like

```
cars=new ArrayList<Car>();
Car car = new Car(descriptionOfTheCar, downPayment, dailyRate);
cars.add(car);
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you didn't initialize your cars ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any details of what is calling addCar() I can't say for certain, but the two most obvious possibilities are that the String has not been initialised or that the ArrayList has not been initialised.

Answer (score 0):

I assume much of your code has been omitted, but from this sample it seems that you haven't initialized your `ArrayList`.